# switching stopped processes in linux bash (using putty)

Tags: linux, bash, putty

Accessing a remote server (Ubunty Hardy) through ssh (putty), i can stop running 'programs' with CTRL-Z (pause signal). I can have multiple paused jobs, which I can see with the command 'jobs'.

The question is regarding if it is possible (or if it already exists) to configure a shortcut to change between processes....

That is, a shortcut equivalent to:

```
PAUSE current process
fg 'next' (brings to foreground the next stopped application)
```

The goal is to achieve an equivalent to ALT-TAB via putty... : )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would probably benefit from `GNU screen` (or the `byobu` variant on Ubuntu) to be able to switch between sessions. That way your other sessions *keep running* rather than being halted / suspended as you propose here.

Comment: yes, it's cool, i tried it... it changes a bit my shell, more features than needed... thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fg %n` where the n is the job id you see in square brackets when using `jobs`.
Also, you can use `fg %-` for previous job.

See http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html Section 3.203 Job Control Job ID

Comment: @niry: Or just do `fg n` without the percent. :) Anyway, I think he's asking if you can configure _one key_ to effectively type `^Zfg $(tail jobs | cut -f1 "-d ")` or similar.

Comment: exactly, that's what i'm looking for

Comment: i know about "fg n", but im looking if its possible to configure a shortcut to do ^Zfg $(tail jobs | cut -f1 "-d ") or similar

Comment: In that case, screen is your friend, my friend. 1up @Dirk.

Comment: From Windows, use putty as before. Then on the server, launch `screen` (or, preferably, `byobu`) and *add additional sessions* between which you can switch.